Key provided is shorter than 256 bits in PHPOpenSourceSaver JWTAuth
I'm working on a Laravel project and trying to implement JWT authentication using the php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth package and I'm having an issue when attempting to generate a token.
my JWT_ALGO=HS256
The error message I'm receiving is:
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException:
Could not create token: Key provided is shorter than 256 bits, only 224 bits provided
below is the code

  try {
            $notActivated = $this->auth->login($credentials);

            if ($notActivated === trans('user::users.account not validated')) {
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => trans('user::users.account not validated'),
                    ],
                    403
                );
            }
            if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
                // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => trans('invalid credentials'),
                    ],
                    401
                );
            }
        }


below is the stack trace for reference:

PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException {#969
#message: "Could not create token: Key provided is shorter than 256 bits, only 224 bits provided"
#code: 0
#file: "Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/Providers/JWT/Lcobucci.php"
#line: 143
-previous: Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\InvalidKeyProvided {#968
#message: "Key provided is shorter than 256 bits, only 224 bits provided"
#code: 0
#file: "Project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php"
#line: 39
trace: {
Project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/InvalidKeyProvided.php:39 {
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\InvalidKeyProvided::tooShort(int $expectedLength, int $actualLength): self …
› {
› return new self('Key provided is shorter than ' . $expectedLength . ' bits, only ' . $actualLength . ' bits provided');
}
Project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/Hmac.php:20 {
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac->sign(string $payload, Key $key): string …
› if ($actualKeyLength < $expectedKeyLength) {
› throw InvalidKeyProvided::tooShort($expectedKeyLength, $actualKeyLength);
› }
}
Project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Token/Builder.php:119 {
Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder->getToken(Signer $signer, Key $key): Plain …
›
› $signature = $signer->sign($encodedHeaders . '.' . $encodedClaims, $key);
› $encodedSignature = $this->encoder->base64UrlEncode($signature);
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/Providers/JWT/Lcobucci.php:141 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci->encode(array $payload) …
›
› return $this->builder->getToken($this->config->signer(), $this->config->signingKey())->toString();
› } catch (Exception $e) {
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/Manager.php:85 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Manager->encode(Payload $payload) …
› {
› $token = $this->provider->encode($payload->get());
›
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php:74 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWT->fromSubject(JWTSubject $subject) …
›
› return $this->manager->encode($payload)->get();
› }
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php:84 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWT->fromUser(JWTSubject $user) …
› {
› return $this->fromSubject($user);
› }
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/JWTGuard.php:164 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWTGuard->login(JWTSubject $user) …
› {
› $token = $this->jwt->fromUser($user);
› $this->setToken($token)->setUser($user);
}
Project/vendor/php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth/src/JWTGuard.php:149 {
PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWTGuard->attempt(array $credentials = [], $login = true) …
› if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
› return $login ? $this->login($user) : true;
› }
}
Project/Modules/User/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php:85 {
Modules\User\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController->postLogin(ApiLoginRequest $request): JsonResponse …
› }
› if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
› // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
}


Things I have tried:

Cleared Cache
Cleared the JWT keys
Regenerated the JWT keys using jwt:generate-certs
Generated a new key manually

This same code works perfectly in another project with same app key and  I tried copying the working version to this project, but I'm still getting the same error.
I'm unable to figure out why the key is shorter than the required 256 bits when i generate one. Has anyone faced a similar issue or could point me in the right direction to resolve this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Try debugging to see when the key changes from its correct value. I assume it's loaded from .env, proof that it's loaded correctly and passed into the JWT package correcty. Does it get mutated? Also consider any platform differences between these two projects (OS, php version, extentions, php ini, etc)

One thing i noticed in the getToken method under Lcobucci\JWT\Token; is that the algorithm is correct but the loaded  key seems shorter than those in my other working project , and this was generated using the   jwt:secret    artisan command  which is the key  used in this section  jwt:secret  

I will try and link the the DB of the other project and use the exact env and see if anything changes. Thanks

The only thing I can come up with is something to do with text/string encoding. Maybe the .env isn't in UTF-8 or PHP isn't running in UTF-8 or something to do with mbstring extention
